# Column string edition in a file, bash sed awk

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have tricky problem with editing one column in a file.
My goal is to repleace strings in second coulmn to get rid of the part separated by \ sign.
To make it clear this is example source file:
aaa.txt

```
0   OS1\admin
1   OS1\test
2   OS3\user
3   OS5\test
4   OS2\test
5   osx\admin
```

Thats how it should be changed

```
0   admin
1   test
2   user
3   test
4   test
5   admin
```

Its drivin me nutss, please help :) Sed / Awk or pure bash would be just gr8

Answer (score 2):

#### sed

```
sed 's/\S*\\//' input.txt
```

#### awk

```
awk '{sub(/[^[:space:]]*\\/, "")}1' input.txt
```

#### bash

```
while read -r x y; do echo $x ${y##*\\}; done <input.txt
```

Comment: `while...` loses proper spacing.

Comment: Then instead of `echo`, use `printf "%-4d%s\n" $x ${y##*\\}` -- adjust the format string to your liking.

Comment: ..Or, to keep it automated: `read -r x; do echo "${x% *\\*} ${x#*\\}"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture the first column, and then remove the first part of the second column?

sed 's/\(.*\t\).*\\/\1/g'

`\\(.\*\t\\)` should be capturing column 1, `.\*\\` should match up to and including the \ in column 2. Then we replace this by `\1`, which is the column 1 that we captured earlier.

Comment: the answer below is better than mine if \ won't occur in any other column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an inline edit to your file you could try the following. REMEMBER TO BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO TESTING ANY INLINE EDIT.

```
sed -i 's/   .*\\/   /g' /yourfile
```

**For OS X** you can try the following (REMEMBER TO BACKUP YOUR FILE PRIOR TO TESTING ANY INLINE EDIT.)

```
sed -i '' 's/   .*\\/   /g' /yourfile
```