# Split string on a backslash ("\") delimiter in awk?

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I am trying to split the string in a file based on some delimiter.But I am not able to achieve it correctly... Here is my code below.

```
awk 'var=split($2,arr,'\'); {print $var}' file1.dat
```

Here is my sample data guys.

```
Col1 Col2
abc  123\abc
abcd 123\abcd
```

Desire output:

```
Col1 Col2
abc  abc
abcd abcd
```

Comment: Your quoting is broken, look closely at colored highlighting.

Comment: Still not able to find it ...

Comment: You can't nest single quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Column string edition in a file, bash sed awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122797/column-string-edition-in-a-file-bash-sed-awk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data and output is my best guess at your requirement

```
 echo '1:2\\a\\b:3' | awk -F: '{ 
     n=split($2,arr,"\\")
     # print "#dbg:n=" n
     var=arr[3]
     print var
     }'
```

**output**

```
b
```

Recall that `split` returns the number of fields that it found to split. You can uncomment the debug line and you'll see the value 3 returned.

Note also that for my test, I had to use 2 '\' chars for 1 to be processed. I don't think you'll need that in a file, but if this doesn't work with a file, then try adding extra '\' as needed to your data. I tried several variations on how to use '\', and this seems the most straightforward. Others are welcome to comment!

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes you will still need to escape `\` even if the awk script is provided in a separate file, rather than supplied on the command-line.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to call split. Just use `\\` as field separator:

```
echo 'a\b\c\d' | awk -F\\ '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a,b,c,d
```

Comment: `echo 'a\b\c\d' | awk -F'\' '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'` also works.

Comment: I executed your awk script but it doesn't work... I am getting ,d,, as output.

Comment: I still get the same o/p for the above one also.

Comment: I also have `GNU awk 3.1.3` on CentOS release 5.5, and when I enter command in my answer I get `a,b,c,d`.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments mentioned, you have nested single quotes. Switching one set to use double quotes should fix it.

```
awk 'var=split($2,arr,"\"); {print $var}' file1.dat
```

I'd prefer piping to another awk command to using split.I don't know that one is better than the other, it is just a preference.

```
awk '{print $2}' file1.dat | awk -F'\' '{...}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslash you're trying to split on. You can do this in you `split` using double-quotes like this: `"\\"`

Also, you can take an array slice to make your code more readable (and avoid defining another var). This should work for you:

`awk 'NR==1 { print } NR>=2 { split($0,array,"\\"); print $1,array[2] }' file1.dat`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/123\\/,"")}1' file

Col1 Col2
abc  abc
abcd abcd
```